# Twitter bootstrap login form always gives validation errors with Laravel 5.2 scaffolded auth

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, authentication

I am using the simple make:auth scaffold to login into my app. It was working fine until I applied some Bootstrap styling to it. Now it always gives the error that **"The username field is required"**, and **"The password field is required"** whenever I try to submit the form.

Here is the login.blade.php:

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <form class="no-margin" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" >Email</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control input-lg input-transparent"
                                   value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Your Email">
                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" >
                        <label for="password" >Password</label>

                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg input-transparent"
                                   placeholder="Your Password">

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>


                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger">
                        <span class="small-circle"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></span>
                        <small>Sign In</small>
                    </button>
                    <a class="forgot" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Username or Password?</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to add the fields `name` to the email input and to the password input, that's why you laravel can't access the values of these input and fire the exception